# TFS lost binding to solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server, revision-control

Right now I have 2 solutions I'm working on.

I checked them both into TFS, but for some reason the changes I make in the 2nd one do not seem to check them out and there is no red check mark next to them.

Also, when I right-click the files in that solution I don't see "history" or "compare" options.

When I right-click the solution to add it to source control it says some of the files are already in source control, but I can't see the history or compare those files by right-clicking on them.

[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I got into this predicament. Likely something stupid on my part.

It turned out some of the files were under source control and some weren't. I clicked "ignore" above and manually added all the missing files.